# Creating a new variable in elements of List using R

Tags: r

I am new to R language. I have a list of 64 elements(1 Element contains 72 observations) and trying to create a new variable with its range using lapply function. Any leads would be highly appreciated

eg:

```
$x
Var1 Var2 
abc   345
def   678
ghi   891

$x2
Var1 Var2 
abc   345
def   678
ghi   891
.
.
.
.
64 elements

required o/p:
$x2
Var1 Var2 var3
abc   345  1
def   678  2
ghi   891  3
.
.
64elements
```

Comment: what does `str(your_list)` return?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to apply a function though out the data frames in the list.

```
# Create an example list
dt <- data.frame(Var1 = c("abc", "def", "ghi"),
                 Var2 = c(345, 678, 891),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt_list <- list(dt, dt)
names(dt_list) <- c("x", "x2")

# Add one new column using lapply
dt_list2 <- lapply(dt_list, function(x){
  x[, "Var3"] <- 1:nrow(x)
  return(x)
})
dt_list2
# $x
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1  abc  345    1
# 2  def  678    2
# 3  ghi  891    3
# 
# $x2
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1  abc  345    1
# 2  def  678    2
# 3  ghi  891    3
```